# ajax to change content from dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a website. I have created a dropdown in it for displaying different data while the user selects different dropdown, my code is as below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// code to get all records from table via select box
$("#course_title").change(function() {
var tid = $(this).find(":selected").val();
var dataString = 'tid='+ tid;
$.ajax({
url: 'mycourses.php',
dataType: "json",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(employeeData) {
if(employeeData) {
$("#heading").show();
$("#no_records").hide();
$("#emp_name").text(employeeData.tid);
$("#emp_age").text(employeeData.training_name);
$("#records").show();
} else {
$("#heading").hide();
$("#records").hide();
$("#no_records").show();
}
}
});
})
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control sel" name="trainings" id="trainings" >
      <option value="select options" selected disabled>Select Training Course</option>
<?                      $sql_trainings = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data";
                      $trainings_data = mysqli_query($con,$sql_trainings);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trainings_data) ){
                          $trainingid = $row['tid'];
                          $training_name = $row['training_name'];


                          echo "<option value='".$trainingid."' >".$training_name."</option>";
                      }
                      ?>


     </select>
```

i have another page as getcourses.php as below

```html
<?php
include "config.php";

$trainingid = $_POST['tid'];   // department id

$sql = "SELECT tid,training_name FROM tbl_data WHERE id=".$departid;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
    $userid = $row['tid'];
    $name = $row['training_name'];

    $users_arr[] = array("tid" => $userid, "training_name" => $name);
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
```

The dropdown is first displayed in a page, then when the user clicks the dropdown, they are taken to different page showing the content of the dropdown they selected, it's showing the content the first time when the user clicks the dropdown and is being taken to the different page to show content, but when the user clicks different dropdown from the result page the dropdown doesn't work, nothing happens, I want to display the content of dropdown which the user selects in the resulting page, whenever user changes dropdown it should be appearing. my table name is tbl_data and my columns are tid and training_name.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#course_title").change(function() {
```

should be,

```
$("#trainings").change(function() {
```

So your js code should be like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#trainings").change(function() {
        var tid = $(this).val(); // this is enough to get selected value
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mycourses.php',
            type: 'POST', // you forgot type 
            data: {tid : tid},
            success: function(employeeData) {
                // same as your code
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: there is no error, when the dropdown is clicked, the page goes to another page displaying the table data, but when the user clicks the dropdown from the resulting page its not showing the data. user has to go back to the old page and then select the dropdown from there